# Specializing template for concept without support of the base template

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, c++03

I have a bunch of classes that implement a concept A and I can detect using some meta-function that a class indeed implements concept A. Let's say

```
template <typename T> struct IsA;

IsA<ImplementsA>::value == true;
IsA<AnythingElse>::value == false;
```

Now there is a concept B. Any class can be made to implement concept B by specializing appropriate traits:

```
template <typename T> struct BTraits { /* whatever */ };
```

(Implemented for bunch of standard types, of course)

I can easily specialize `BTraits` for any class that implements concept A. That would however mean adding the specializations all over the place and pull in heavy dependencies that I only need in part of the cases.

The usual approach of <strike>`template <typename T> struct BTraits<T, typename enable_if<IsA<T> >::type> { ... }`</strike> will *not* work, because the base template does not have the extra argument defaulted to void.

So is there any other way to specialize `BTraits` for anything that `IsA` that wouldn't need that extra argument? I can modify the A concept (e.g. add a base class or something), but I can't modify the B concept.

Unfortunately I am stuck with C++03 compilers for some platforms, so it has to be C++03 compatible (in C++11, the concept B wouldn't need the traits, only functions that are easy to overload).

Comment: Is there a default-implementation for `BTraits`? Otherwise you don't have to specialize, just define the default implementation...

Comment: @DanielFrey: Of course there is a default implementation of BTraits and a bunch of existing specializations. Making the default specialization work with the classes is backup plan, but I would prefer to avoid it since it would pull in many extra headers in more places than I need them.

Comment: Can you modify the internals of `BTraits`? I mean, if you can't add another template parameter, can you modify the implementation of the primary `BTraits` template?

Comment: @dyp: No, I can't. It comes from a library.

Comment: @JanHudec are you responsible for any instantiation of `BTraits`? ie. are you the one writing `BTraits<SomeType>`, or is that up to the library?

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp: No. It is declared by a library. I can only specialize it.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no *safe* way to specialize `BTraits<T>` in a way that would make it a better/most suitable match for any `T` where some other `other_trait<T>::value` yields true.

*Explicit template-specialization* does not care if a certain *type template-parameter* belongs to a certain set of types. The compiler either sees an exact match, and instantiates the *specialization*, or it doesn't; which means that the *primary template* will be instantiated.

When the compiler tries to find a suitable specialization to use, it's not like during function call where an object is potentially, and implicitly, convertible to one if its potential *base-types*, that one is selected.